# What is the smallest possible focusable, scaleably intense laser design?

Tags: electromagnetism, lasers

Would anyone here have any ideas towards what the smallest possible laser mechanism across all physical potential might be? I was wondering this for a theoretical machine capable of manipulating billions of atoms in quick succession with electromagnetic beams, but came to the conclusion that ultimately, the speed of this machine would be decided by the laser to atom ratio, and so I tried to figure out the smallest possible design for a practical, stable, focuseable laser, yet I didn't even know where to start with such a prediction.

Thanks in advance for your time and consideration:^)

Comment: I have a friend who has built leading-edge laser lithography for semi-foundries in the nm range..

Comment: Cool! thanks for your input!

Comment: Are you asking about the size of the laser-generating material or the size of the spot produced on your target material?   In the latter case, you can go to sub-wavelength spot sizes by using an aperture of desired diameter which transits almost in contact with the target material's surface.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75  I found a 10-nm class device here https://spie.org/news/3765-shorter-wavelength-extreme-uv-sources-below-10nm?SSO=1  ,  and 3 nm (paywalled) https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/135351 .  I suspect your friend's laser is not that short and external optics manipulate the final spot size (or at least intensity profile)

Comment: I heard from a close friend that he was down to 1 nm resolution of etching